# Win32: Storing debug info to survive crash

Tags: windows, debugging

I'd like to store some info somewhere for debugging purposes, if my program crashes. On the next start I would read this information. I could do this in the registry or file system, but that's not very fast. I could use shared memory and a second process, but I'd like to avoid running a second program all the time.

I'd like to know if there is any faster way for this. Is there any windows mechanism (pipes, shared memory, whatever) that is fast and not lost if a program crashes?

Comment: Have you considered using WER? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487440.aspx), or is it a bit overkill for you?

Comment: Registry is a bad idea. Just dump it to a text file, like everyone does. Program folder can sometimes be read only (if You install it in Program Files and UAC is enabled), so do it in c:\users\public.

Comment: I don't like the idea of a text file too much as well... Mind you, it's not bad but... An alternative is to use the Application Event Log; you can see it later in the event viewer, or read it programmatically at next startup

Comment: @dema80 Event viewer is also good, but just remember it has some limit of characters. I just experienced this when i wanted to analyze chkdsk log - it DIDN'T fit there (if there are disk errors it can become quite large), although i didn't care to search what are the limits.

Comment: @Kitet good point, but AFAIK the limitation is only in the viewer: if you read events programmatically, it should be ok. But I may remember the wrong thing..

Comment: Sorry, WER isn't an option. Too expensive (several hundred $) and probably not compatible with Armadillo

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the Application Event Log:
(C# code here, but you can do it unmanaged as well)

```
string cs = "MyAppEvents";
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
   EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, "Application");    

EventLog.WriteEntry(cs, message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

Events written there are sent to a service, which may be fast enough.
The architecture of the event logging service is explained here:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/winlog/chapter/ch02.html
(it is old, but has not changed much)

EDIT: it WAS changed since the days of NT4 :) 
Never versions of windows (>2000 - NT5) have a more efficient feature called Event Tracing. You can read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx

A reasonable implementation should use a named pipe between advapi32 in your process and the services, which on the same machine uses shared memory maps (in fact, there is a named pipe called "eventlog" among the others you can find in an windows system)

Comment: Event log would work, but it's actually too much. I just want to store a few bytes info (like the current index of a loop). I just tried the "named pipe" in general and that seems to be destroyed as soon as you close the pipe.

Comment: Named pipes handles are closed as soon as the process is closed; you cannot use them to "store" data; think of them like sockets. I'm curious, why Event Log is "too much"? It's fast, it's not so difficult to implement, it's reliable. (Not talking about ETW here, just Event Log)

Comment: Imagine calling system function 10000 times in a loop. I'd like store data before and after each call, so I have more info if the system function crashes. That's a lot of data in the log. Especially since I'd only need the *last* entry.